# Importing facebook birthday list to my android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to import facebook birthdays of my friends to my app. Currently my app is capable of creating new birthday events. But its very long procedure to add each and every birthday, so instead I want a code to import all facebook friends birthdays to my app. I have used facebook session but get nothing much till now

```
facebook = new Facebook(Constants.FB_APP_ID);
    Session session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), session.getState().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), session.getState().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
```

Also i have created a request

```
private void importBirthdayFromFB() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on fb button",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fbRunner.request("maxparera/friends", new RequestListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            String keys = "";
            try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(response);
                // getting name of the user
                Iterator<String> keysIterator = profile.keys();
                if (keysIterator != null) {
                    while (keysIterator.hasNext()) {
                        keys += keysIterator.next().toString();
                    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), keys, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                final String name = profile.getString("name");
                // getting name of the user
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Name: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

But I am not getting any name, instead getting exception, sating OAuthException
Please suggest me ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your session dont have permission to get your friend's birthday.
You can request permission like below:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends, read_friendlists));
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I uses Facebook SDK 3.8, you can refer to its sample for more detail.
LoginButton is a component of Facebook SDK.

For full of my code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            Log.i(TAG, "session: " +session.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "state: " +state.toString());
            if(exception!=null)
                Log.i(TAG, "exception: " +exception.toString());
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
//REQUEST PERMISSION
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends, read_friendlists));

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            try{
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
                Log.i(TAG, "Execute my request");
                Request r = new Request(session,"/me/friendlists",null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted");
                                try {
//I HAD FRIEND LIST
                                    Log.i(TAG, "FRIEND: " + response.getGraphObject().toString());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    );
                r.executeAsync();

                Log.i(TAG, "Finish my request");
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            }

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            try{
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
     // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: working with facebook is very complex if you're not familiar with Facebook SDK and working with Facebook. If you only need data to test, you should not waste effort for this.